# Vim and screen: background color not reset when exiting vim

Tags: bash, screen, vim

I use vim in a screen session.

Whenever I end editing a file and exit vim the background of my terminal stays the
same as in vim, rather than resetting correctly as it does when I am not using screen.

One way I found to reset the colors is to use the cls command I have defined as `alias cls='printf "\033c"` and then pressing a couple of times `CTRL+L`

I was wondering if there is some setting I can change either in .bashrc, .vimrc or .screenrc
to make things work properly.

So far I have added this to my .screenrc to make sure vim colors are the same both when in screen sessions and when not:

```
caption always "%{= kc} %n -- %t -- %-21=%{= .m}%D %d.%m.%Y %0c"

attrcolor b ".I"
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
defbce "on"
```

Comment: Thanks your config (last three lines) plus the answer's line doing he best. The first result in google search is http://robotsrule.us/vim/ but for me it is doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a line with `altscreen` in your `~/.screenrc`. If you don't have such a file, create it.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/223898/on-quit-less-does-not-clear-its-contents-when-run-in-a-screen-session